# Pass Variable to NEW Form vs. OPEN Form

Tags: vb.net

I have a WinForm that I want to pass a variable to.  This form may or may not already be open.  The code I was using would check to see if the form was open (using an `IsOpen` function) and then do a `.BringToFront` if it was open, or it would do a `.Show` if it was not open.

Now with trying to use `New()` to pass the variable, things are not working as expected.  Creating the form variable, using `Dim AdBook As New frmAddressBook`, means a new instance of the form is created.  When I run the `IsOpen` function, it does see the form.  However, since I created a "new" form, when I run the `AdBook.FillPatientInfo` function of that form, the other variables have not been set up because that "new" form has not actually been loaded.

The only solution I have found thus far is to close the form and then open it again.  But that sounds like more overhead than it should be.  And besides, I'm not sure how I would close a form that I can't get a hold of.

Form 1 Click Event:

```
Private Sub tsmiAddressBook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsmiAddressBook.Click
    If IsDBNull(dgvPhysician.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value) Then Exit Sub

    Dim AdBook As New frmAddressBook(CInt(dgvPhysician.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value))

    If IsOpen(AdBook, Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name) Then
        AdBook.BringToFront()
        AdBook.FillPatientInfo(CInt(dgvPhysician.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value))
    Else
        AdBook.Show(Me)
    End If
End Sub
```

Form 2 New() code:

```
Private intID As Integer = Nothing
Public Sub New(ByVal newID As Integer)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    intID = newID
End Sub
```

Code that checks to see if form IsOpen:

```
Public Function IsOpen(ByVal frm As Form, SubName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim frmCol As New FormCollection()
        frmCol = Application.OpenForms
        Dim Cnt As Integer = 0
        For Each f As Form In frmCol
            If f.Name = frm.Name Then Cnt += 1
        Next
        Return CBool(IIf(Cnt > 0, True, False))
    Catch ex As Exception
        CustExErrorMsg("Functions", Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Couldn't you add an interface on your the forms you want to interact with, that has a method that can be called instead?

Comment: Creating a new form object when there might be another one already loaded is of course troublesome.  Using Application.OpenForms has pretty sharp edges as well.  Just keep a class-level variable around of the form type, set it to Nothing with the FormClosed event.  So if it IsNothing then you know you need to create a new instance, if it isn't then you just need to restore it.  [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3023745/17034).